# Convert attribute lang as xml:lang in groovy or Java script

Tags: xml, groovy

I am getting an attribute "lang" in xml that should be converted as "xml:lang" leaving other elements and attributes untouched and also add DOCTYPE tag as second line. I need to use the code in SAP HANA Integration Platform.

please help me sharing Groovy or javascript code to achieve above.

For example:input

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
    <Description lang="en">TEST</Description>
    <Forecast>
    <Period endDate="2016-09-01T23:59:59+02:00" startDate="2016-09-01T00:00:00+02:00"/>
    <ForecastQuantity quantity="34.0">
    <name lang="en">TEST1</name>
    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
    </ForecastQuantity>
    </Forecast>
    </root>
```

Output should be:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.029/cXML.dtd">
    <root>
    <Description xml:lang="en">TEST</Description>
    <Forecast>
    <Period endDate="2016-09-01T23:59:59+02:00" startDate="2016-09-01T00:00:00+02:00"/>
    <ForecastQuantity quantity="34.0">
    <name xml:lang="en">TEST1</name>
    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
    </ForecastQuantity>
    </Forecast>
    </root>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the attribute name like:

```
def startXml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<Description lang="en">TEST</Description>
<Forecast>
<Period endDate="2016-09-01T23:59:59+02:00" startDate="2016-09-01T00:00:00+02:00"/>
<ForecastQuantity quantity="34.0">
<name lang="en">TEST1</name>
<UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
</ForecastQuantity>
</Forecast>
</root>"""

def parser = new XmlParser()
def root = parser.parseText( startXml )
root.Forecast.ForecastQuantity.name[0].replaceNode{
name( 'xml:lang': root.Forecast.ForecastQuantity.name.@lang[0],
     root.Forecast.ForecastQuantity.name[0].value() )
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( root )
```

Produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Description lang="en">TEST</Description>
  <Forecast>
    <Period endDate="2016-09-01T23:59:59+02:00" startDate="2016-09-01T00:00:00+02:00"/>
    <ForecastQuantity quantity="34.0">
       <name xml:lang="en">TEST1</name>
     <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
    </ForecastQuantity>
  </Forecast>
</root>
```

Comment: Getting error >groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceNode() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@25b31d24]
 at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:15)

Comment: I get the same error using https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ but works fine running as script using 2.4.6 in intellij